# Is there a sculpt brush which is just moving mesh?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I want to adjust clothes to character using a sculpt mode, because basic `scale/move/rotate` is not enough for me. I just want to move mesh part outside of character by dragging it. So, maybe there is a suitable brush or addon for it? I've tried to use basic `draw` brush and it's breaking original shape of clothes.

Comment: did you try the grab brush?

Comment: @Alex Thank you! It's cool thing but I can't understand how to use it correctly. In front view I can drag verticies to all directions except to me, so i need always look at mesh from side (which is not comfortable). It's still right answer but can you provide more details?

Comment: I posted a more complete answer, hope that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the grab brush to adjust a mesh shape. If you just click and drag, it will move the affected points on the X and Y axis from the current viewpoint. It is mostly used to change the silhouette of the mesh.

If you hold CTRL while you click and drag, it will "push" the affected vertices on their normals. It wont move them towards you, but this is pretty close

[image: grab]

You can as well use the inflate brush, which is pretty good when you need to fit clothes on characters without breaking the original shape too much. It does more or less the same thing as the grab brush when you hold CTRL, the only major difference is that it behaves more like a pen

[image: inflate]